# Google Custom Search with SEO URL

Tags: seo, submit

Well i have this search engine into my site

```
<form action="/apps/search/" name="g_search" id="cse-search-box" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11;NB:1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="google_seach" class="search-text" onfocus="searchtext('focus')" onblur="searchtext('blur')" />
    <label style="color:#796b6b;float:left;padding:0;">|</label>
    <input type="submit" style="float:right;margin-top:3px;cursor:pointer;width:16px;height:16px;background:url(/template/img/main/search-icon.jpg);border:none;" value="" alt="Αναζήτηση" title="Αναζήτηση" />
</form>
```

Now i want some code to results page.Somehow the post request readed from a file called search.php
This file have access to $_POST[] array..

The file initializes $selector variable (for template use).
What we want to echo into contentarea div must put into $body variable..
Any help?

```
<?php
    $selector="search";
    $body="<div id=\"cse-search-form\" style=\"width: 100%;\">Loading</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, just use GCS code provide by Google as it easy, make sure in the option in GSE you select to visualize the search result on your page and not an Iframe